# Why this database access code doesn't work? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an Access database with columns titled `Key` and `Username` and I'm trying to set some data back to the `Username` column of the first row of the database. But I get an error:

> Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

The code:

```
 Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        Dim connection_string As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.UserAppDataPath & "\DDL.mdb"
        Dim strSql As String = "SELECT Key,Username FROM table1"
        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand
        'Dim dataset As DataSet
        Using cnn As New OleDbConnection(connection_string)
            cnn.Open()
            Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
                dad.Fill(dtb)
                '/// send data from datatable to database
                Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(dad)


                command.Connection = cnn
                command.CommandText = "update * from table1"

                'set data
                dtb.Rows(0)("Username") = "PG"
                dad.Update(dtb)

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT: P.S:** I did some edits to the code, still gets that error

Comment: [It says Item isn't a property. Maybe you are looking for Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: If you have an MS Access database, why are you trying to use MS SQL Server provider objects?

Comment: @Plutonix: OMG, yes, why did I do that . it should be `OleDbDataAdapter` I guess .. it makes that entire code incorrect I guess. :/ and the `connection` is also wrong. :/

Comment: I should edit the whole question.

Comment: I edited the whole question. now gets a different error

Comment: You have a column *named* "Key", but is it actually the primary key for the table? That's what it wants. [Add or change a table’s primary key in Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-change-a-table-s-primary-key-in-access-07b4a84b-0063-4d56-8b00-65f2975e4379). If another column is the key, you can put that into the SELECT command and simply not display it/use it in this program.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Thank you very much, it solved that issue.

Comment: @Pretty_Girl3 Hang on, I'll make that into an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a column named "Key", but is it actually the primary key for the table? That's what it wants.

There are two options:

(1) You don't have a primary key in the table. To solve that, add one or assign a current column to be the primary key. [Add or change a table’s primary key in Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-change-a-table-s-primary-key-in-access-07b4a84b-0063-4d56-8b00-65f2975e4379).

(2) If another column is the key, you can put that into the SELECT command and simply not display it/use it in this program.

The reason is that when it creates the UPDATE command it uses the primary key to identify which row to update. When it performs the SELECT it performs an extra query first to get information about the table, which will include which column is the primary key; it uses that information when creating the UPDATE command.

Comment: I tried to set primary key via the : `"ALTER TABLE " & table_name & " ADD PRIMARY KEY(" & "Key" & ")"`  this has a syntax error: `Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause.` what is wrong?

Comment: You should only have to do it once, so I wonder why you're doing it in the program instead of in the Access program. However, I think it needs to be more like `ALTER TABLE [tableName] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Key PRIMARY KEY ([Key]);`. It's going to be awkward because "Key" is a [reserved word in Access](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe).

Comment: it works now. Thank you. The reason I'm doing it is, I'm programmatically making a access database, and then filling some data, retrieving data, changing data etc. So, it's easier for me to set the primary key through code after I make the file, so I don't have to do it manually. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `dtb.rows(0).item("Name")` for the Name in the first row of the datatable

Use `DirectCast(dtb.rows(0).item("Name"),String)` to use the value as a string.

```
TextBox10.Text = DirectCast(dtb.rows(0).item("Name"),String)
```

Mind possible Null-Values in the Database. They will cause an exception in the example above. Check for Null-Values as follows:

```
If IsDBNull(dtb.rows(0).item("Name")) then
    TextBox10.Text = ""
Else
    TextBox10.Text = DirectCast(dtb.rows(0).item("Name"),String)
EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the DataAdapter with an Update command. You can do this manually by setting the .UpdateCommand property of the adapter.

`dad.UpdateCommand = "Update table1 Set`...

Or you can use the CommandBuilder method. This will generate the commands for you based on your Select query. (Insert, Update, Delete)

```
Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(dad)
```

Comment: now it gives me a different error: `Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.` .. and I updated the code

Comment: Does your table in the database have a primary key? If it does add that column to your select statement.

Comment: If your table doesn't have one it probably needs one. You need to have a primary key to uniquely identify a record. Without a unique identifier the database can't Update or Delete a single record.